# Object.assign methods not binding 'this'

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to bind the `this` variable to a new object.

```
function Parent(){
    //sub-component constructors
    this.components={
        node:function(){
            this.name = 'jordan';
        }
    },
    //subcomponent methods
    this.ctrl={
        nodes:{
            type1:{
                test1:function(){
                    console.log('firing');
                    console.log(this);
                    //return undefined should return 'jordan'
                    console.log(this.name);
                },
                test2:function(){
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
//INIT
function init(){
    //CREATE NEW 
    var parent = new Parent();
    var props = {
        "ctrl": parent.ctrl.nodes.type1
    };
    //OBJECT ASSIGN 
    var node = Object.assign(new parent.components.node(),props);
    console.log(node);
    //WHY ISN'T THE (THIS) VARIABLE SET WHEN I CALL
    node.ctrl.test1();
}
//EXECUTE INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

**Question:** Why isn't the `this` variable being set from the `Object.assign()` when I call `node.ctrl.test1()` which `console.log(this.name)`?

Comment: `parent.components.node` is a function. Did you really mean to assign to that object?

Comment: Which `this` do you expect to be set to what? And no, `Object.assign` doesn't bind anything.

Comment: I'm using it as `constructor` to a sub-object (sub-component) thats relative only to it's `parent` object.

Comment: To use it as a constructor, you need `new`, not `Object.assign`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah your right, I just updated the code take a look, still logging `undefined`

Comment: Because you are still invoking the `test1` method on `node.ctrl` (you should see this from the `console.log(this)`).

Comment: @Bergi ugh yeah because I'm declaring `function test1` creating the new scope... thing is if I shorthand `()=>` the `this` variable gets set to `parent` object. Is there anyway to get it where `this.name` returns the object name, post answer so I can give you credit man.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter how you declare it. It matters how you call it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definition of `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(target, ...sources)
```

This means that `Object.assign(parent.components.node,props)` assigns the `props` object to `parent.components.node`, overriding the function previously assigned to it.

Calling `node.ctrl.test1()` works in the same way as if you tried to call `props.ctrl.test1()`, which obviously won't work.

`new parent.components.node()` won't work either, because you will be assigning `props` to an object returned from using `node` as a constructor function. That object will only have a `name` property.

Comment: yeah your right I wan't instantiating a new object just operating on that current one.

Comment: I updated my code with `new` so it instantiates a new instance, making the `parent.components.node` a constructor, still when I call `node.ctrl.test1()` it still logging `undefined` for  `console.log(this.name)`