# Object.assign rebind of functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

since I need reputation and can't actually comment on this thread: [Object.assign methods not binding 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809794/object-assign-methods-not-binding-this/44809930#44809930?newreg=093ae0532d1946b0b63f6c262d18d4e6)
Im opening my own question:

Can this be somehow solved or workarounded? I have a "master" object containing

`function init(){ console.log(this) }.bind(this)`

I am cloning this master object into other object and i want the init function run with the scope of the slave object, not the master.
Is there any option?

Comment: Bound functions cannot have their `this` value bound again. So, you cannot clone and re-bind. You should probably avoid binding the first time around.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the master object itself is instantiable and it needs to have binding to itself. But thanks I got it, I will need to rethink the base structure.

Comment: "*and it needs to have binding to itself.*" most likely it doesn't. If you're doing something like `.on("someEvent", master.someMethod)` then you can substitute for `.on("someEvent", () => master.someMethod())` and then you wouldn't need `someMethod` to be bound. In general, the value of `this` is only "lost" if you pass the method as a reference.

Comment: I will check that. Thank you again

Comment: …or you need to use a `clone` method to use instead of `Object.assign`, which can clone the methods and then bind them afterwards. Could you please [edit] your question to share more of your code for that master object so we can write a proper answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved my problem thanks to this:

https://gist.github.com/cowboy/5373000

In case the URL is down, here is the additional code:

```
Function.prototype.bind = (function(origBind) {
  return function() {
    var fn = origBind.apply(this, arguments);
    fn.__origFn__ = this.__origFn__ || this;
    return fn;
  };
}(Function.prototype.bind));

Function.prototype.unbind = function() {
  return this.__origFn__;
};
```